# Bypassing --allow-file-access-from-files in three.js examples

Tags: google-chrome, three.js

I was looking at three.js examples that I downloaded on my PC, and suddenly I noticed that I was loading local textures without problem.

I have rechecked my local examples, and I still need to set the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.

Is there a trick that I don't know ?

It would very nice to forget about always setting this flag !