# JSONLoader not working with me

Tags: three.js

My problem is threejs loader examples are only work on (http://threejs.org)
when i load the examples on my PC then run it from my desktop it's not working.
such as: (http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_gltf)

please advice me !

Comment: is the problem on chrome or firefox or both?

Comment: oh ... my goodness when you asked i go and download Firefox then tested and it work well out so what the problem with chrome ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is different permissions between browsers. You need to start chrome with

```
"chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files"
```

even though this fellow ([Bypassing --allow-file-access-from-files in three.js examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24023053/bypassing-allow-file-access-from-files-in-three-js-examples)) is reporting the opposite of what you are reporting.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a local server to prevent this.

You can achieve this by downloading Node.js (http://nodejs.org/download/) and then installing this package (https://www.npmjs.org/package/http-server).

When you are done you cmd to the project folder and execute:

```
http-server -p <port number>
```

And then when you browse localhost, you get your index.html and files from a virtual server.

---

Another solution is to use WebStorm IDE, that itself creates a server.

Comment: ya ,, but if i have already domain site and i want to uploaded ?